# Graphhopper No-go areas routing

Tags: android, extents, geospatial-pdf, mapsforge

I am creating a simple **offline** navigation app in **android**. I have camera information(coordinates and range) and i would like to navigate the routes to avoid being caught on cameras. I have seen great example https://graphhopper.com/blog/2015/11/15/publess-routes-graphhopper-edition/ here.

What I **have tried** is that I have changed weights of the edges direclty connecting to cameras (problem here - is the modified weights persist even after restarting/uninstalling app).

What i **need** is in addition to the edges directly connecting to cameras, I would like to change weights of edges that lies in circles centring at the cameras.

I think I have read somewhere before that mapsforge provides a library with geospatial opertaions and I can't seem to find it again now.